# Shell script when i have to use while loop

Tags: shell

I am newly learning shell script.
Shell script when i have to use while loop ?
what is the definition of while loop ?

could you please give me some clear information on this ?

Thanks lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process untill you meet your criteria you must use `while` loop.
Ex. in below code we are running loop untile c is less than 5, we we dont know how much time loop will run? its unpredictible but its must to run untill we meet our criteria.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    echo "Welcone $c times"
    (( c++ ))
done
```

If you know certain number of time you have to run loop you must use `for` loop, this is simplst definition
Ex. in below code we know the end and its predictive that we will print the message 5 times.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

Comment: could you please give me any sample code while and case should be come one program ?

Answer (score 0):

i should prefer to use this link that help you when to use and what is the way to use 
and how to use

[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/while-loop.htm)

sample loop code
while command
do
   Statement(s) to be executed if command is true
done